# password_verify выдает false при корректных данных

Tags: php

Всем привет, пишу свой мини блог, написал авторизацию и регистрацию, и при регистрации задаю пароль 228, далее пробую авторизоваться под этими данными, и функция password_verify выдает false. Пробовал выводить отдельно чистый пароль в суперглобальном массиве $_POST, захэшированный пароль, и ответ password_verify, данные корректны, но все равно выдает false, что я делаю не так?

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

require_once 'app/database/queries.php';

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password_pre = $_POST['password'];

$password_user = selectAll('users', ['login' => $login]);

$password_hash = $password_user['password'];

$password = password_verify($password_pre, $password_hash);

pre($password_pre);
pre($password_user);
pre($password_hash);
var_dump($password);
```

---

```
228
Array
(
    [id] => 451
    [login] => saluteismyname
    [email] => saluteismyname@gmail.com
    [password] => $2y$10$5dYrDYc51XPxRY/A0ur4x.EG0DCMMBpKwm0XpG/E/9pfdFTnp90VS
    [admin] => 0
    [created_at] => 2023-09-25 07:36:02
)
$2y$10$5dYrDYc51XPxRY/A0ur4x.EG0DCMMBpKwm0XpG/E/9pfdFTnp90VS
bool(false)
```

Comment: Как вы получаете хэш который хранится в базе `$password_user['password']`? что выводит `pre(password_hash($password_pre))`

Comment: вывод вроде один должен быть - в базе не те данные, которые вы ожидаете.

Comment: pre(password_hash($password_pre)) - выводит пароль, который ввел пользователь в форму(228)

Comment: А получаю с помощью функции selectAll, и ниже, после 228 - это то, что возвращает функция selectAll

Comment: `pre(password_hash($password_pre))` выводит хеш. Вот и сравни этот хеш с хешом из БД.

Comment: В данном конкретном случае, *разумеется*, у вас некорректный хэш.
Корректным хэшем от строки '228' c такой солью будет `$2y$10$5dYrDYc51XPxRY/A0ur4x.wPR55HLdCIjfKO.IyhsZbpljPvUtY1.`
И если вы подставите его в `password_verify()` то получите true.

Это означает, что в БД лежит хэш не строки `'228'`, **а какого-то другого пароля.** К примеру, если БД кривая, то в ней может быть два пользователя с одинаковым логином

Comment: Я знаю, что вы не указывали соль. Она добавляется автоматически

Comment: По ошибке я хэшировал логин, а не пароль, да уж...

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!